# Find the length of the tangent to the circle if the perimeter of the triangle is $8$.

Tags: geometry

From the point $O$, two tangents are drawn to a circle such that the perpendicular to one of the tangents at its point of contact with the circle $Q$ meets the other tangent at $P$. If the perimeter of triangle $POQ$ is $8$ units, find the length of tangent to the circle from the point $O$. 
[image]

I've tried taking angle $POQ=2\theta$ and applying trigonometry to solve the question but I've not had any success so far.

Comment: I think you need to specify the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green marked angles are equal. Then, we have $\triangle PQ’S \sim \triangle POK$.

[image]

We further assume that $\triangle PQ’S = k \times \triangle POK$; for some non-zero k.

If $OQ’ = x$, then $PQ’ = … = \dfrac {k}{1 - k}x = tx$, for short and $t = \dfrac {k}{1 - k}$.

Similarly, PS = tr; where r is the radius of the circle.

From $\triangle PQ’K$, we have $(tr + r)^2 = r^2 + (tx)^2$. After simplifying, we get $t = \dfrac {2r^2}{x^2 – r^2}$.

Finally, $2x + \dfrac {2r^2}{x^2 – r^2} (x + r) + 2r = 8$. From which, x can be found if r is known.

Comment: I took a peak at the back of the textbook and the answer is expressed in terms of r. Then they've taken the case of a unit circle, in which case the answer is $2$, which I'm getting from your equation.

Comment: @VishnuV.S Good. Maybe you should revise your question accordingly and mark the amendment as EDITed.

Answer (score 2):

**This problem is undetermined** as @Barry Cipra just remarked. Here is why.

Let $OQ=a$ and $QP=b$. The objective is to find $a$.

Perimeter constraint

$$\tag{1}a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=8$$

can be written in an equivalent way: $(a+b-8)^2=a^2+b^2$ (with condition $a+b<8$ ). Expanding and simplifying, we arrive at the (still equivalent) condition

$$\tag{2}b=8\dfrac{4-a}{8-a}$$

It means that you can choose any $a$, $0 \leq a \leq 4$, there will always exist a unique other possible "leg" side $b$ given by (2), thus there will always exist a right triangle fulfilling condition (1).

**Remark**:

a) Limit cases $a=0$ and $a=4$ are associated with "flat triangles".

b) A rather simple case is obtained with $a=2$, giving $b=8/3$ and $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=10/3$. The sides thus obtained are proportionnal to the sides $3,4,5$ of the simplest "pythagorean triple".

---

**Edit**: Once you have any of these right triangles, you build the circle:

- whose center $C$ is at the crossing of the angle bissector of $\widehat{QOP}$ and line $PQ$ and
- whose radius is $CQ$.

Comment: You didn't use anywhere the fact that OP and OQ are tangent to the same circle

Comment: How do you know that every right triangle with perimeter 8 achieves that condition?

Comment: @J. P. C. once you have the triangle, you can built the "ad hoc" circle. I am going to say some words about it as an edit to my answer.

Comment: @J. P. C. For your second question: it is because I can proceed all the way long with an equivalence. May be, I could explain it in my proof.